# How to quickly move to the end of generated braces/parenthesis/etc in Visual Studio with Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

My google fu is failing me.  Visual Studio and Resharper helpfully provide closing brackets and the like.  For example, typing "var foo = new Foo(" immediately inserts a ).  Great!  So I go to insert a bunch of other stuff.  I know I can just type in the closing characters and it'll gloss over fine, but when I do something like this...

```
var foo = new Foo(new Bar()
{
    Something = 48,
    SomethingElse = new Fred(new Bob())
};
```

Right after typing Bob the rest is generated.  I want to be able to cleanly move to the end of that generated code and move to the next line without touching the arrow keys.  A simpler example:

```
if (something)
{
    Something();
}
```

That last curly brace is made for me, but I want to go past it without touching the arrow keys.  Is there any shortcut that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep typing. Type the closing ")" (ReSharper will move past it), then the semicolon (ReSharper will enter it).

Comment: Yep, I know that one.  And I just tried it on multiline... and it works.  Huh.  That part I didn't know.  That'll work fine then!