# Skip over auto-completed parenthesis in ReSharper 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

ReSharper automatically completes open parenthesis in method calls, and I like that.  I want it to continue doing that.  However!  Is there some easy way to move the caret past the auto-completed parenthesis?

For example, when I type:
`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(`

I am given the closing parenthesis immediately:
`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`

Then I add "Test" as the parameter:
`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test")`

But now, my caret is immediately before the closing parenthesis.  It's annoying to move my hand to the `END` key, or to the arrows just so I can skip over the auto-completed parenthesis so I can add a semi-colon:

`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test");`

Neither `TAB` nor `ENTER` do what I want.  And the answer given here: [How to quickly move to the end of generated braces/parenthesis/etc in Visual Studio with Resharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651552/how-to-quickly-move-to-the-end-of-generated-braces-parenthesis-etc-in-visual-stu) advises me to just go ahead and type the `)`.  But then what's the point of automatically closing the parenthesis if I'm going to type it anyway??

Comment: I don't know if Resharper is messing up your key binds or if this is new in VS 2015, but <tab> does what you want in VS 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely end your current statement and go not only beyond all ')', but also beyond ';', then you can use Complete Statement feature (Ctrl+Shift+Enter). See more info here http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html

Otherwise there is no such a feature because when you need to skip just one ')', you'd still need to press a key to go over ')', and Enter or Tab are not better than ')' or right arrow - no use to change one for another.

Comment: Note this also works for VS 2013, for which I had the same question.

Comment: Enter and Tab are both better than ')' or right arrow. ')' requires two keypresses because I have to hold shift, and right arrow is away from home row and requires me to move my right hand a long distance then back. Enter and Tab can both be pressed from the home row position with very little effort. The difference quickly becomes relevant when it happens for *every* line of code you type, all day, every day.

Answer (score 0):

[image: resharper]

Uncheck that box! :) all it will stop auto completion of brackets!

Comment: "ReSharper automatically completes open parenthesis in method calls, and I like that. I want it to continue doing that."